# Computation of real MTF and comparison with theoritical MTF

Tags: optics

Before explaining my problem I have to explain the context:
I want to modelize a detector. I assume that the PSf of this detector is an Airy disk. Knowing the characteristics of the detector, I can compute the analytic MTF.

But this analytic MTF will not be observed, because the detector is made up of pixels. To modelize it, I intergate the PSF over the pixels. It gives me a discrete PSF, as it can be seen below:

[image]

From this discrete PSF I calculate the MTF (the discrete MTF, or as it will be called later in another image, the numerical MTF).

(and to be very precise, I compute 2 MTFs, one for each direction)

Here is the discrete (numeric) MTF (blue curve) and the analytic MTF (red curve) the other curves represent the discrete MTF multiply by different analytic MTF taking diffraction into acount.

[image]

So here are my problems, the blue curve does not goes to 0 amplitude at 1 cy/pix, for the high spatial frequencies. I think it is due to the discretization but I do not really understand why. I would be very glad if someone could explain me the physical meaning of this. I have seen some experimental MTF doing the same on some websites.

My second problem is that as you can see, the discrete MTF is better than the analytical one for high spatial frequency. Do you think my calculations are wrong because of this?

For the calculation of the MTF, I do the discrete fourier transform of a row (or a line) of the PSF, with one point per pixel.

PSF stands for point spread function and MTF for Modulation transfer function.

Please tell me if something is not clear so I can update my post.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Point Spread Function (PSF) is an Airy disk, it is smooth. The Modulation Transfer Function (MTF) is the magnitude of the Fourier Transform of the PSF. It is also smooth, and has relatively little high frequency components.

The pixelated PSF is a stair step function, full of sharp changes. These have much larger high frequency components. The MTF does not drop to 0 as quickly.

I would expect the pixelated MTF to the the product of the Airy disk MTF and a square wave MTF. The second part corresponds to a PSF where a point of light becomes a full pixel.

Also I would expect that the Airy disk MTF takes diffraction into account. You don't need to multiply by another MTF for that.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. Now I wonder what is the best way to compute the MTF to compare with the analytic one. I could use the pixelated PSF or I could use an oversampled PSF but in this case, I do not see how to normalize the MTF obtained to have the x axis in cy/pix as the shape changes with the number of points chosen (I know it should be trivial, I'm sorry to ask this).

Comment: If you are taking one measurement per pixel, your data does not have the sharp changes in it that would add to high frequency components.  The highest frequency your computed Fourier Transform will provide is determined by the distance between samples. At 1 sample/pixel, it will be 1/2 cycle/pixel. Often you would measure distance in mm instead of pixels, and report the answer in cycles/mm. Also, you should look into using one 2D Fourier Transform instead of two 1D transforms.